# Is there any better way to handle if else condition in logic app?

Tags: azure, if-statement, azure-logic-apps

In logic app i have one myarray variable with values `['1','2','3']`

In the `Foreach` connector it will come one value a a time and want to check which value it is and based on that set a value to another variable.

in c# it will be like -

```
foreach (item in myarray)
{
if (item == 1)
{
 set variable_data = 1
}
else if (item == 2)
{
 set variable_data = 2
}
else if (item == 3)
{
 set variable_data = 3
}
```

in logic app i can able to do it like this - 
[image]

is there any better way to do it in logic app?

Comment: What feature you want， please specify it in detail。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-switch-statement) action to implement this requirement.
[image]

Comment: Switch works when you are comparing one variable for multiple possible values, as shown in the example. But if we have multiple variables to check, like if a==1 else if b==2 else, it may not work.